# Encoding.ASCII.GetString for ReadOnlySpan<byte>

Tags: c#

Is there a way, using the .NET Framework, to get a String from a ReadOnlySpan  without calling .ToArray() on the span ?

I can see that there's an overload for .NET Core
https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Text.Encoding.GetString(ReadOnlySpan%3CByte%3E)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubtful. The .NET Framework proper does not support `Span` and its family since it requires CLR work (and it appears the .NET Framework is sunsetting). Here's a thread you can follow: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/770